# How to reach a property of a generic interface with other non-generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Let me list all of my current classes and interfaces:

IItem:

```cs
public interface IItem<T> where T : ItemData {
    T Data { get; }
}
```

Item:

```cs
public class Item<T> : IItem<T> where T : ItemData {
    T data = null; // I am setting this something else later on

    T Data => data;
}
```

Equipment:

```cs
public class Equipment<T> : Item<T>, IEquipment where T : EquipmentData {
    // Code...
}
```

How can I get Data using IEquipment? Thanks.

Comment: How would like to get a property via interface, that doesn't implemented by class? `IEquipment` can be implemented by class, that doesn't inherit the `Item<T>`

Comment: What is `IEquipment`?

Comment: @dymanoid I have a method called AddEquipment(), it takes an IEquipment in it as a param since I can't use Equipment<>, I have to declare the generic type for that.

Comment: You don't provide the `IEquipment` definition, hence my question.

Comment: It contains mostly properties that Equipment do for the reason above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly, you need some cast first.

```
IEquipment equipement = new Equipment();

// ...

// 'object as type' will cast the object with the corresponding type if possible, else return null
var data = (equipement as ItemData)?.Data; // data will be null if cast is not possible
```